# MYSQL union All with condition if condition matched choose first else 2nd

Tags: mysql, union-all

In my case it is  permissions and roles so i combined result with union all 
I just want check condition if user permission value = 0  then pick this else other one i am trying like this

```
SELECT username, orgId, uid, pid, perm FROM (
    SELECT users.username, users.orgId, user_roles.uid, role_perms.pid, role_perms.value AS perm
                    FROM user_roles INNER JOIN role_perms
                    ON (user_roles.rid = role_perms.rid) INNER JOIN user_users ON(user_roles.uid = users.uid) WHERE role_perms.pid = 9 AND users.orgId = 2 AND users.username IS NOT NULL AND users.username != ''
                    UNION ALL 
    SELECT users.username, users.orgId, user_perms.uid, user_perms.pid, user_perms.value AS perm
                    FROM user_perms INNER JOIN users ON(user_perms.uid = users.uid) WHERE user_perms.pid = 9 AND user_users.orgId = 2 AND user_users.username is not null and user_users.username != '') AS combPerm;
```

It gives result as if permission is denied for one user in user_perm table but that user also have role that contain particular permission

```
username | orgId | uid | pid | perm
abc@a.com  2       11    9     0
abc@a.com  2       11    9     1
xyz@a.com  2       91    9     1
dvc@a.com  2       88    9     1
```

In result i want abc@a.com only one time if it has perm 0 from user_perms table and all other record same, desired result is as

```
 username | orgId | uid | pid | perm
abc@a.com  2       11    9     0
xyz@a.com  2       91    9     1
dvc@a.com  2       88    9     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just take the `min(perm)` and add a group by to your query

```
SELECT username, orgId, uid, pid, min(perm) FROM (

 -----the rest of the query

) AS combPerm group by username, orgId, uid, pid;
```

Comment: No This will group by results which i already tried this not full fill condition of if user_perms.value = 0 then priority should be to that else to role_perm

Comment: please provide more sample data and your desired results.

Comment: @user3712320: It is not clear why you are not satisfied with this answer. It seems to do exactly what you have asked for: perm 0 has precedence over perm 1 for username + orgId + uid + pid. So please clarify.

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner  i accepted this anwer but  now question came in my mind still its not complete if role_perms has 0 but user_perms have 1 then it should not get result with 0 because priority should be based on user_perms table,

Comment: @user3712320: It is good you've accepted this answer. I've posted another answer that kind of builds up on this solution and should solve the query precedence you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You have accepted isaace's answer on how to give perm 0 precedence over perm 1. But now you say, you would rather give query 2 results precedence over query 1 results.

In standard SQL this would be easily done. You'd add a rank key to the queries (`select 1/2 as rankkey, ...`) and rank your results with `ROW_NUMBER` and keep the best match or you'd do this with `FETCH WITH TIES`.

MySQL does neither support window functions such as `ROW_NUMBER` nor a limit clause that allows for ties. Many such things are solved with variables in queries in MySQL. Here is another trick:

What you have is something like

```
select username, orgId, uid, pid, perm from table1
union all
select username, orgId, uid, pid, perm from table2;
```

and isaace has shown you how to get the minimum perm per username, orgId, uid, pid. You however want somthing close but different :-) Here you go:

```
select username, orgId, uid, pid, max(keyperm) % 10 as perm
from
(
  select username, orgId, uid, pid, perm + 10 as keyperm from table1
  union all
  select username, orgId, uid, pid, perm + 20 as keyperm from table2
)
group by username, orgId, uid, pid
order by username, orgId, uid, pid;
```

What is happpening here? You see I add 10 to the perm in the first query and 20 to the perm in the second query. `MAX` gives me the higher of the two, which is the second if both are present. We end up with a perm that is either 10 or 11 or 20 or 21. The operation % 10 (modulo ten) removes the ten's place and only keeps the one's place, which is 0 or 1, the perm.

(If perms can be two digits, add 100 and 200 and use %100, if more digits ... well you got the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM (YOUR QUERY) t WHERE perm=0 GROUP BY username, orgId, uid,pid;`

Comment: This not gonna work if its so simple then whats need of UNION or UNION ALL